# rndc: 'reload' failed: not found

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, rndc

I would appreciate help on this. I tried myself, see below.

```
cp 40.129.98.db 40.234.173.db

nano 40.234.173.db
```

(modified IP in the file to reflect 173 IP, updated SERIAL)

```
named-checkzone /var/named/40.234.173.db

root@server [/var/named]# rndc reload 40.234.173.in-addr.arpa
rndc: 'reload' failed: not found
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't tell BIND about *new* zone files with `rndc`, you have to add the zone configuration into the `named.conf` file, and then use `rndc reconfig`.

FWIW, I believe future versions of BIND may have support for the nascent "nscp" (name server control protocol) which is being discussed at the IETF.  That protocol *is* intended to allow name servers to add whole new zones "on the fly".

Comment: Thanks, but it would help if you tell me what the command is?

Comment: I did - edit named.conf to add the zone file, then run `rndc reconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the named.conf, take name from line with string zone and reload it. For example:

zone "v6.domain.com.pl"{

rndc reload zone v6.domain.com.pl

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to create the zone file. You also need to tell bind about it, which is normally done in named.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this error will also show up when the bind server is **not actually started** (when run on localhost)